# Springdoc - Child classes fields are not getting added to the swagger spec schema

Tags: swagger-ui, springdoc, swagger-core

I'm using spring-boot v2.6.7 and springdoc v1.6.8. Below is the object modeling. I have added one endpoint which returns the Course as the response. I am expecting swagger spec to generate the types for the Course and the Child type which is EnglishCourse also there's an **items** field on EnglishCourse which is supertype of CourseItem and there are subtypes for it which are Folder, Lesson, and Test. I expect swagger spec to include a proper schema definition for all the subtypes.

```
package com.example.springdocdemo.domain

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema
import java.util.UUID

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(
    value = [
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EnglishCourse::class, name = "EnglishCourse")
    ]
)
abstract class Course {
    abstract val id: UUID
    abstract val name: String
    abstract val code: String
}

class EnglishCourse(
    val items: List<CourseItem>,
    override val id: UUID,
    override val code: String,
    override val name: String,
) : Course()

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(
    value = [
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Folder::class, name = "FOLDER"),
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Lesson::class, name = "LESSON"),
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Test::class, name = "TEST")
    ]
)
@Schema(discriminatorProperty = "type", allOf = [Folder::class, Lesson::class, Test::class])
interface CourseItem {
    val type: CourseItemType
    val id: UUID
}

@Schema
class Folder(
    val items: List<CourseItem>,
    override val id: UUID,
    override val type: CourseItemType,
) : CourseItem {
    fun items() = println(items)
}

class Lesson(
    val name: String,
    override val id: UUID,
    override val type: CourseItemType,
) : CourseItem

class Test(
    val name: String,
    override val id: UUID,
    override val type: CourseItemType,
) : CourseItem

enum class CourseItemType {
    Folder, Lesson, Test
}
```

and the below is the schema definition for the Folder type

```
"Folder": {
    "required": [
      "id",
      "type"
    ],
    "type": "object",
    "allOf": [
      {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CourseItem"
      }
    ]
  },
```

It doesn't include fields id and items. Is there any solution for this? The code can be found here: https://github.com/BhaveshSuvalaka/springdoc-issue

Comment: Have you tried something like this - https://www.davideaversa.it/blog/document-kotlin-spring-application-springdoc-openapi/? Specifically at the bottom of the post with generics.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try

```
@Schema(subTypes = {EnglishCourse.class})
```

Comment: this doesn't work. I have tried.